# Swift can't infer conditional type in a loop

Tags: swift, casting, typechecking

When I'm casting views with `case let` Swift properly recognizes the type of `circle` to `PinCircleView` inside the loop

```swift
 for case let (index, circle) as (Int, PinCircleView) in pinCirclesStackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
    print(index, circle) // <- circle is PinCircleView and print's as expected 
 }
```

But if I'm type checking with `is` Swift still only allows me to access `circle` as it would be `UIView`

```swift
for (index, circle) in pinCirclesStackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() where circle is PinCircleView {
  print(index, circle) // <- circle is UIView but print's PinCircleView
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly `is` does not cast but only checks the type, but this leads me to another question if the type is matched why can't I "fully" use it?

Comment: Okay that's right but still I perform a type-check after that, shouldn't it operate on the resulting Tuple? If some of those view's won't be of Type `PinCircleView` they won't appear in loop afaik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift types are established at *compile time*.

In the first case, the `case let` only assigns values to `(index, circle)` if the types are `(Int, PinCircleView)`.  So at compile time, Swift knows `circle` is of type `PinCircleView`.  You can verify this by <kbd>option</kbd>-clicking on `circle`.

```
for case let (index, circle) as (Int, PinCircleView) in pinCirclesStackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
    print(index, circle) // <- circle is PinCircleView and print's as expected
}
```

In the second case, `(index, circle)` gets assigned every value from `arrangedSubviews.enumerated()`.  In that case, `arrangedSubviews` returns `[UIView]` and `.enumerated()` turns that into a sequence of `(Int, UIView)` tuples.  So in this case, `circle` is a `UIView`.

The `where circle is PinCircleView` then checks if `circle` contains the `PinCircleView` subclass of `UIView`, but it doesn't change the fact that `circle` is typed as `UIView`.  Again, use <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `circle` to verify that its type is `UIView`.

```
for (index, circle) in pinCirclesStackView.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() where circle is PinCircleView {
    print(index, circle) // <- circle is UIView but print's PinCircleView
}
```

Inside of the `for`, you know that `circle` contains a `PinCircleView`, but Swift doesn't.  You could downcast it inside of the loop with `let pincircle = circle as! PinCircleView` and know that it would always work without crashing because you checked it using `is`.

But the better form is to use the `for case let` version to properly establish the type of `circle` as `PinCircleView`.